# Aurelia Validation - possible to validate one by one?

Tags: validation, aurelia

I have a simple login form - username and password. I'd like to validate each field but only upon success of the previous one i.e. only validate password if email has succeeded. This is because I'm targeting mobile and I really only want to display the first error message due to limited real estate.

Is this possible? It seems like something that ought to be possible with the fluent API:

```
this.validator = validation.on(this)
        .ensure("email")
            .isNotEmpty()
            .isEmail()
            .isBlocking() //something like 
        .ensure("password").isNotEmpty();
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for - https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/doc/Intro.md#configcomputedfromarrayofbindingpaths

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create more than one validator.

```js
this.emailValidator = validation.on(this)
        .ensure("email")
            .isNotEmpty()
            .isEmail()
            .isBlocking();

this.passwordValidator = validation.on(this)
        .ensure("password")
        .isNotEmpty();
```